# how to convert snowflake table to different structure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

| id | name | DESCRIPTION | ACTIVE | UPDATED_JSON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | name-1 | desc-1 | true | {"diffFields": [{"fieldName": "name","valueAfter": "**new-segment-name-1**","valueBefore": null},{"fieldName": "active","valueAfter": true,"valueBefore": null}],"segmentId": "b204c220-ea8d-4cf4-b579-30eb59a1a2a4"} |
| id2 | name-2 | desc-2 | true | {"diffFields": [{"fieldName": "name","valueAfter": "**new-segment-name-2**","valueBefore": null},{"fieldName": "active","valueAfter": true,"valueBefore": null}],"segmentId": "b204c220-ea8d-4cf4-b579-30eb59a1a2a4"} |

I have a table of the above structure in snowflake. `UPDATED_JSON` is a variant column. I want to change this table to have the structure similar to the one below.
In `UPDATED_JSON` I have `fieldName`, when its value is `name` I need to update the `name` column to have `valueAfter` data. `diffFields` is not ordered. If `name` in `updated_json` is not present, I want to leave `name` column with its current value.

in the below example , `name-1` changed to `new-segment-name-1` because `UPDATED_JSON` has a `fieldName` with value `name` and `valueAfter` with value `new-segment-name-1`

| id | name | DESCRIPTION | ACTIVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | new-segment-name-1 | desc-1 | true |
| id2 | new-segment-name-2 | desc-2 | true |

I am trying to to this with dbt

Comment: when you say "you are doing this with dbt", what do you want us to do with that information? Are you wanting us to only provide DBT valid SQL or only dbt transform constructs? because you have two problem, how to doa transform in snowflake, and how to make dbt do that transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you data as a CTE:

```
WITH data(id, name, DESCRIPTION, ACTIVE, UPDATED_JSON) as (
    select column1, column2, column3, column4, parse_json(column5) from values    
    ('id1', 'name-1', 'desc-1', true,'{"diffFields": [{"fieldName": "name","valueAfter": "new-segment-name-1","valueBefore": null},{"fieldName": "active","valueAfter": true,"valueBefore": null}],"segmentId": "b204c220-ea8d-4cf4-b579-30eb59a1a2a4"}'),
   ('id2', 'name-2', 'desc-2', true, '{"diffFields": [{"fieldName": "name","valueAfter": "new-segment-name-2","valueBefore": null},{"fieldName": "active","valueAfter": true,"valueBefore": null}],"segmentId": "b204c220-ea8d-4cf4-b579-30eb59a1a2a4"}')
)
```

```
select id
    ,max(iff(f.value:fieldName::text = 'name', f.value:valueAfter::text, null))  as name
    ,DESCRIPTION
    ,active
from data, table(flatten(input=>UPDATED_JSON:diffFields)) f
group by 1,3,4;
```

gives:

| ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | ACTIVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id2 | new-segment-name-2 | desc-2 | TRUE |
| id1 | new-segment-name-1 | desc-1 | TRUE |